# Combining Sikuli with PyModel testing: ImportError: No module named org.sikuli.basics

Tags: jython, sikuli

I'm using Jython 2.5.3, PyDev, Sikuli 1.0.1 and Eclipse Luna on Mac OS X.
After I added the Python-Path enviroment variables and the PyDev external libraries with Sikuli itself everything is working fine.
Also the PyModel samples are working on my mashine.

Now I want to combine Sikuli with PyModel testing(http://staff.washington.edu/jon/pymodel/www/).
But when I try to execute the a simple Sikuli test with PyModel I get the following message:

```
('', 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pmt", line 8, in <module>
    pmt.main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymodel/pmt.py", line 180, in main
    mp = ProductModelProgram(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymodel/ProductModelProgram.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.module[mname] = __import__(mname) 
  File "/Volumes/MBT_Py/PyModel/samples/handshake/handshake.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sikuli.Sikuli import *   
  File "/Volumes//MBT_Py/sikuli/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from org.sikuli.basics import Debug
ImportError: No module named org.sikuli.basics
')
```